# Universal family of grassmannian as projective bundle over $\mathbb P^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grassmannians, chern-classes

Let $p:X=\mathbb P(\mathcal E_2)\rightarrow Gr(2,n+1)$ be the universal family of the lines in $\mathbb P^n$. If we denote $e:X\rightarrow \mathbb P^n$ the natural projection, we have $\mathcal O_{\mathcal E_2}(1)=e^*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$.
It seems that $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P(T_{\mathbb P^n})$, $e$ being the projection, and that $\mathcal O_{T_{\mathbb P^n}}(1)=p^*\mathcal O_{Gr(2,n+1)}(1)$ where $\mathcal O_{Gr(2,n+1)}(1)$ is the polarization given by the Plücker embedding.
But it seems not to be true since when I compute the first Chern class of $X$ using the first description I get $c_1(T_X)=(n+2)p^*c_1(\mathcal O_{Gr(2,n+1)}(1)) + 2e^*c_1(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1))$ whereas using the second one I get $c_1(T_X)=np^*c_1(\mathcal O_{Gr(2,n+1)}(1))+ 2(n+1)c_1(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1))$. So, where is my mistake?

Comment: For a point $[L]\in \text{Gr}(2,n+1)$ parameterizing a line $L\subset \mathbb{P}^n$, the fiber $p^{-1}([L])$ of $p$ over $[L]$ is canonically isomorphic to $L$.  The natural invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}_2}(1)$ restricted to $L$ is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ restricted to $L$.  However, the natural invertible subsheaf of $T_{\mathbb{P}^n}|_L$ is $T_L \cong \mathcal{O}_L(2)$.  So the pullback of $\mathcal{O}_{T_{\mathbb{P}^n}}(1)$ is certainly not the pullback of an invertible sheaf via $p$.  Rather, it equals $p^*(\mathcal{O}(1))\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}_2}(-2)$.

Answer (score 3):

The variety $X$ is the partial flag variety $Fl(1,2;n+1)$. With respect to the projection to $P^n$ it is most naturally written as the projectivization of the bundle $T(-2)$. The reason is the following.

Denote by $V$ the vector space of dimension $n+1$, so that $P^n = P(V)$. Then on $P(V)$ one considers the Euler sequence
$$
0 \to O(-1) \to V \otimes O \to T(-1) \to 0.
$$
Its exterior square then is the sequence
$$
0 \to T(-2) \to \Lambda^2V \otimes O \to \Lambda^2T(-2) \to 0.
$$
Thus, $T(-2)$ canonically embeds into the trivial bundle with fiber $\Lambda^2V$, and this embedding induces a morphism $P(T(-2)) \to P(\Lambda^2V)$ that factors through $Gr(2,V) \subset P(\Lambda^2V)$.

EDIT. Let me describe the construction of the first map in the second sequence. First, note that we have a natural map 
$$
V \otimes O(-1) \to V \otimes V \otimes O \to \Lambda^2V \otimes O
$$
(the first map is the identity of $V$ tensored with the canonical embedding of $O(-1)$; the second is the alteration).
It is easy to see that the composition of this map with the embedding $O(-2) \to V \otimes O(-1)$ (the $O(-1)$-twist of the canonical embedding) is zero (because of the alteration). Therefore the map $V \otimes O(-1) \to \Lambda^2V \otimes O$ factors through $Coker(O(-2) \to V \otimes O(-1)) \cong T(-2).$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask, please, what is the first map of the exterior square and have you got a reference for these exterior powers (because Eagon-Northcott complexes are or seem different from your sequence).

Comment: @pi_1: I added an explanation.

Comment: Thank you again. So one just analyzes an Eagon-Northcott complex.